# What is this UFW rejected traffic that I'm seeing?

Tags: networking, traffic

I know that `192.68.1.1` is my router and I know that `224.0.0.1` is a broadcast address and I've deduced that `192.68.1.14` is my old Roku. I don't see any mention of what port is being hit. I do use DDNS but turning it off seems to have no effect. Any ideas?

```
May  9 11:41:52 hostmachine kernel: [217434.611111] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp8s0 OUT= MAC=[redacted] SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=44551 PROTO=2 
May  9 11:42:18 hostmachine kernel: [217459.840883] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp8s0 OUT= MAC=[redacted] SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=44552 PROTO=2 
May  9 11:42:43 hostmachine kernel: [217484.726835] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp8s0 OUT= MAC=[redacted] SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=44553 PROTO=2 
May  9 11:43:08 hostmachine kernel: [217510.408467] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp8s0 OUT= MAC=[redacted] SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=44554 PROTO=2 
May  9 11:43:10 hostmachine kernel: [217512.006897] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp8s0 OUT= MAC=[redacted] SRC=192.168.1.14 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=62712 PROTO=2
```

This crap is filling up my logs.

Comment: Go into `GUI ufw` and turn of the logging... launch it from dash, go to preferences and select `off` for logging

Comment: Its from your router check these: https://superuser.com/questions/739481/what-might-these-connection-attemps-mean and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483717/what-is-the-multicast-doing-on-224-0-0-251

Comment: Well it seems I have been under attack according to the router logs but they aren't getting anywhere. They are broadcasting from China to see who has opened port 22. I don't have password auth turned on anyway and UFW is keeping it all out regardless. Maybe I should block it at the router though.

Comment: Glad your ufw was on else...

Comment: My momma didn't raise no dummies. ;-)